# Mahout Grouplens Example: How migrate from Jetty to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, mahout

I followed the steps to install and execute (with success) the Grouplens example using Mahout.
Here are the steps:

- Unzip mahout-distribution-0.7-src.zip to c:\mahout-distribution-0.7
- go to c:\mahout-distribution-0.7
- Run: mvn install -DskipTests
- And then, start servlet using this command:

> mvn jetty:run

The above commands work right for me.

But now I want "integrate" Mahout inside Tomcat, so without using Jetty.

Does someone can tell me the exact steps to follow (for Mahout above installation), because I don't know Tomcat.
I think that it can be done fast, using a pair of commands (that I don't know).

All tutorials online uses Jetty, but I'm sure that your answer will be helpul for a lot of people that need to run Mahout in Tomcat.

Thank you very much.
Geltry

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Mahout, but I'm pretty sure there won't be a pair of commands that can replace mvn jetty:run with something similar that runs the same app in tomcat.

mvn jetty:run starts the jetty-maven-plugin which is really great. You'd need to reconfigure that to a similar tomcat plugin.

So unless there's a very good reason you want to switch to tomcat, I'd just stay with jetty. So why do you want to switch to tomcat again?

Cheers,
Thomas

Comment: Because I'm afraid that when I migrate from my home-made server to a commercial server, it will "expose" to me Tomcat, that is most used... (I think, I'm a noob)

Comment: On a root server you can install whatever servlet engine you like best. Then it's best you stay with jetty as you don't have to change the standard and can stick with tools like mvn jetty:run you use right now. Even lots of servers with a preinstalled servlet engine can be ordered with jetty. However I'd recommend a root server and that you install whatever servlet engine you use yourself. That way you're not depending on a version installed and updates from your provider, etc.